# How to block the package mathptm locally?

Tags: pdftex, mathptmx

I declare the package `mathptmx` in the preamble, but I want to use `\mathcal` for the letter I without `mathptm`:

The symbol omega is prettier with `mathptm` but `\mathcal{I}` is not.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptm}
\begin{document}
$$\mathcal{\omega}$$
$$\mathcal{I}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use `$$....$$` -- use `\[...\]`. But that's not the cause of your 'problem'. In addition `mathptm` is regarded obsolete